# sort by latitude in geodjango

Tags: django, geodjango

I have the following model:

```
class Stop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    point = models.PointField()
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

I want to sort my stops from north to south. How do I do this?
`Stop.objects.order_by('point')` sorts them west to east.

thanks.

This is my full model:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Stop(models.Model):
    gtfs_stop_id = models.IntegerField(db_index=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    point = models.PointField()
    parkings = models.GeometryCollectionField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:stop', args=(self.id,))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: You always can do `Stop.objects.order_by('point__x')/Stop.objects.order_by('-point__x')` or   
`Stop.objects.order_by('point__y')/Stop.objects.order_by('-point__y')`

Comment: thanks, but this gives an error:
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'x' into field. Join on 'point' not permitted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your point field is Geometry and not geography you are in luck.

```
from django.db.models import F, Func
Stop.objects.annotate(lat=Func('point',function='ST_X')).order_by('lat')
```

I am using ST_X here instead of ST_Y because PostGIS the best of the geodjango databases the convention is to store `lng,lat`

If you your point field had been geography the above function call will not have worked because [ST_X](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_XMax.html) and ST_Y are only available on geometry fields. Geography fields need to be cast to Geometry before you can use these functions.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this gave me error. I've ended up using extra for this.
Stop.objects.all().extra(select={'lat':'ST_X(point)'}).order_by('-lat')

Comment: Oh, sorry  I see it now. I had used 'location' instead of 'point' in my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please see if it works now, if not post the error and try to avoid the use of extra.

Comment: thanks. this still fails with the same error. TypeError: Improper geometry input type: <class 'float'>

Comment: Well that means you are not using a point field in your model! Please post your actual model. I tested this query before posting it.

Comment: That early clearly indicates that the field you have used in your query isn't a geometry type!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same TypeError: Improper geometry input type:  reported by eran, and I was, in fact, using a PointField. I solved the issue by adding an ExpressionWrapper to tell Django what type of output to expect (a float rather than a point).

Also, in PostGIS to obtain the latitude you should use ST_Y.

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, ExpressionWrapper, Func
Stop.objects.all().annotate(lat=ExpressionWrapper(Func('point', function='ST_Y'), output_field=FloatField())).order_by('lat')
```

Comment: This is the only syntax working for me. Thanks for sharing!